# using css in wysiwyg for custom page

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, theming

I want to allow my end users the ability to save custom css (sass would be better) along with the page content that they edit in a WYSIWYG. I know they can put styles inline but sometimes it's useful to be able to use css selectors instead. Is there a module that will allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Module, no. At least none I know about. You can, however, add text field for css rules and output it inside style tag in your template. Would require some clever javascript to show it in realtime during edit, but should be possible without to much hacking.